# Does anyone knows about Ethiopian numerals?

Tags: reference-request, number-systems

I'm wondered if anyone could give me best resource about Ethiopian(Geez) Numerals and Could you write Geez on LaTex?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Your second question is probably better suited for [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: See [this](http://geez.org/Numerals/images/NumberTable2-cropped.gif), as well as the last two pages of [this](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1200.pdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://www.geez.org/Numerals/) site by Dr. Abera Molla may help you. Especially, [this](http://www.ethiopic.com/ethiopic/numerals.pdf) paper has almost everything that you needed to know about Ethiopian numerals.